# How does the UK declaration for FAA pilots work?

Tags: easa-regulations, caa-uk-regulations, eu

I came across http://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/SRG2140_Issue02_Enabled.pdf

This seems to suggest that an FAA PPL doesn't have to go through any exams / checkride / etc (other than the rudimentary "confirmation knowledge of Part FCL Air Law and ATC procedures") in order to be allowed to fly up to 28 calendar days per year in UK airspace.

Can anyone share additional details on how this process works, such as how long does it typically take to have the declaration verified, what costs (if any) are involved, whether this process has to be repeated every so often or is permanent, etc. ?

Comment: Word of advice - if you intend on doing it get your paperwork to the CAA _well_ in advance (like 6-8 weeks at least) or pay for the over-the-counter service at Gatwick airport. The CAA are about the slowest organisation in the world.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would quote the relevant parts of the document.

Comment: @Jamiec thanks for the tip. Do you have some links or additional info on such over-the-counter service? Can I get the entire process done on the spot, same-day, by just getting to their office at Gatwick?

Comment: @GJ.https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/Applications/Process/Gatwick-airport-over-the-counter-service/ its not walk-in, by appointment only. Be prepared to wait, even if you have an alotted time. CAA is a (bad) joke.

Answer (score 9):

Having gone through this process, I thought I'd share my experiences and timescales:

Useful Docs:

- https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/InformationNotice2017029.pdf
- http://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/SRG2140_Issue02_Enabled.pdf

**1 Oct 2018**

Get a checkout from an instructor and get them to sign the SRG2140 form and also certify copies of the docs required (log book, licence, medical etc, - details on SRG2140 form)

See https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/Applications/Documentation/How-to-get-copies-of-your-documents-certified/ for details on how copies are certified i.e. the wording that must be used.

Scan and submit my SRG2140 form to the CAA via email to pilotvalidation@caa.co.uk

**25 Oct 2018**

Phone the CAA and talk to a very helpful person who says I need to

- also send in SRG2142 and use fclweb@caa.co.uk
- pay £45

So I filled in that form and sent it off by email again with my CAA reference number in the subject and to fclweb@faa.com and pilotvalidation@caa.co.uk

**29 Oct 2018**

Got a phone call (that I missed) and an email asking for my credit card details to pay the £45
I called them back and paid the money
Later that day I got another email confirming they had sent a request to the FAA and suggesting I chase the NAA:

*We are contacting you to inform you that we have processed your application for the Verification of your Third Country ICAO licence, and a verification request has been sent to the FAA. 
To help ensure that the verification is received in a timely manner, you may wish to contact the NAA directly. Additional requirements may need to be met in order to release your personal details to the UK CAA.*

**8 Nov**

I discovered that the FAA has an online portal that allows you to request a validation report so I went to https://amsrvs.registry.faa.gov/amsrvs/main.asp and asked it to send a report to me and also directly to fclweb@caa.co.uk and pilotvalidation@caa.co.uk

**12 Nov**

Received the validation receipt:

*As the current holder of an FAA licence with a validating medical certificate, you are entitled to exercise the private privileges of the ratings for which you are qualified on your FAA certificate in UK Airspace without remuneration.
Please note that your privileges on G-registered aircraft are restricted to day VFR regardless of the medical held, as stated in ORS no.1228: ORS4. FAA Certificate holders with a valid IR flying N-registered aircraft may continue to exercise IFR privileges in UK Airspace. 
Should you be ramped checked, you will have to produce a copy of your declaration made on form SRG2140 and a copy of this email.*

So now I can fly G-Reg aircraft in the UK.

In hindsight, if I had to do it all again I would:

- submit both forms at the same time
- once they had taken the money, gone on to the FAA website and request the validation be sent directly to the two CAA emails addresses

Next step is to do a conversion to an EASA licence which involves:

- (a) pass a written examination in Air Law and Human Performance;
- (b) pass the PPL, BPL or SPL skill test, as relevant, in accordance with
  Part-FCL;
- (c) fulfil the requirements for the issue of the relevant
  class or type rating, in accordance with Subpart H;
- (d) hold at least a Class 2 medical certificate, issued in accordance with
  Part-Medical;
- (e) demonstrate that he/she has acquired language proficiency in accordance with FCL.055;
- (f) have completed at least 100 hours of flight time as a pilot.

As per https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?qid=1524553458669&uri=CELEX:02011R1178-20160408

ANNEX III – Part B “CONVERSION OF LICENCES”

Comment: Very nice first post, welcome to our site!

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you just add for how long do the declaration-based privileges last? And if not indefinitely (while the FAA license is valid), then what procedure should be done to extend it, and how often?

Comment: @GJ I'm not sure how long they last, IIRC my instructor said it was 12 or 24 months.  I am going for an EASA conversion so hopefully that will be in place before the FAA validation lapses